# Azure creating policy with "deployIfNotExists" effect with powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I stumpled upon a interesting way to use Azure policies. https://github.com/cloudignition/Azure/blob/master/AzurePolicy/AzPolicy-BUEnroll.json I tried to test this by deploying it with powershell. However, I do get 'Could not find member 'mode' on object of type 'PolicyRule'

Tried to add that "mode": "all" after the policyrule but that did not help. How could I create that definition with powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by first splitting the before mentioned json into two files "buepolicy.json" and "buepolicy-parameters.json". Basically moving the parameters into the parameters file. Then I can create a new definition with powershell with:

```
New-AzureRmPolicyDefinition -Name "buenroll" -policy buepolicy.json -Parameter buepolicy-parameters.json -Mode All
```